# Non-primary foreign keys in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have two tables from a legacy database that I want to access from a Django site. They look like this:

```
Table A
id (int, primary key)
name (string, unique)
...

Table B
id (int, primary key)
name
record_date
(name, record_date are unique together)
...
```

How do I tell my Django model that Table `A` has a one-to-many relationship with `B` on `A.name=B.name`? The regular `ForeignKey` relationship would require that `B` use `A.id` instead of `name`, but I can't modify the structure of the existing legacy database.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use the [`to_field`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field) and [`db_column`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.db_column) options.

```
class B(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(A, to_field="name", db_column="name")
```

Once you have created the foreign key, you can access the value and related instance as follows:

```
>>> b = B.objects.get(id=1)
>>> b.name_id # the value stored in the 'name' database column
>>> b.name # the related 'A' instance
```

Answer (score 36):

Django's models.ForeignKey documentation is not very clear.  If you have two models reflected in a database:

```
class Blockchain(models.Model):
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True, unique=True)

class Wallet(models.Model):
    index = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    wallet = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    blockchain = models.ForeignKey(Blockchain, to_field="symbol", db_column="blockchain")
```

The "to_field" is actually the name of the field in the Foreign model.

The "db_column" is the name of the field that you want to rename the foreignkey to in the local model

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. the example is generic and avoids confusions with the original question field names.

Comment: Why do you need `db_column="blockchain"` on field `blockchain` in `Wallet`, when the field is already called `blockchain`?

Comment: Otherwise the field will be called blockchain_id as per standard Django naming.

Comment: It's important to note that the `to_field` *must* be unique.