# Django Primary key acting as a foreign key

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a MySQL database with 9 tables. They are all related in some way, but I am having trouble with being able to connect with foreign keys. For example here are two of my tables that I am getting an error when I try to python manage.py migrate:

```
class Release(models.Model):
     release_ID = models.CharField(max_length=25, primary_key =True)
     releaseversion = models.CharField(max_length=25)
     model_ID = models.ForeignKey(Model, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #comes from Model class

class Subrelease(models.Model):
     subrelease_ID = models.CharField(max_length=25)
     release_ID = models.ForeignKey('Release', blank =True) #comes from Release class 
     subreleaseversion = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

How would I make the primary key from class Release, which is release_ID also be the ForeignKey release_ID in class Subrelease? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

After I run migrate I get this in cmd:

```
django.db.utils.InternalError: (1829, "Cannot drop column 'id': needed in a foreign 
    key constraint 'app_subrel_release_ID_id_8e08450_fk_app_release_id' of table
    'db.app_subrelease'")
```

**UPDATE:**
Is this good/okay to do? I don't have any errors when migrating to DB ?

```
class Release(models.Model):
     #release_ID = models.CharField(max_length=25, primary_key =True)THIS WILL BE OUR PRIMARY KEY MADE BY DJANGO
     releaseversion = models.CharField(max_length=25)
     model = models.ForeignKey(Model, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #comes from Model class model_ID



class Subrelease(models.Model):
     #subrelease_ID = models.CharField(max_length=25) THIS WILL BE OUR PRIMARY KEY MADE BY DJANGO
     release = models.ForeignKey(Release, on_delete=models.CASCADE ) #comes from Release class release_ID
     subreleaseversion = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

Comment: "An error"? Sharing is caring.

Comment: Can you format your indentation correctly?  What error? Traceback?  Also, I don't think you want blank=True as a foreign key

Comment: oops, Sorry I forgot to post the error. Thanks for letting me know. I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use the [`to_field`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field) and [`db_column`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.db_column) options.

```
class B(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKeyField(A, to_field="name", db_column="name")
```

Once you have created the foreign key, you can access the value and related instance as follows:

```
>>> b = B.objects.get(id=1)
>>> b.name_id # the value stored in the 'name' database column
>>> b.name # the related 'A' instance
```

reference:
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31412377/non-primary-foreign-keys-in-django)

Comment: I tried this but I get this error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ForeignKeyField'

Comment: @Carbon, that's because it is supposed to be just `ForeignKey`, not `ForeignKeyField`